# Is it possible for a working person remain healthy just by 4 hours sleep a day?

Tags: sleep, work, dreaming

Due to work pressure, I'm feeling that 24 hours is not enough to finish it in deadline. I've tried it for two days but felt impossible. I'd heard that successful person do not sleep long. I don't know how true is it. But I find impossible to continue working without good healthy sleep. In fact, I also have dream inside  tag. It sounds funny but it is fact...

Comment: Even when I usually disagree with moderators casting single close vote, I have to agree this time since this question is not suitable for this site. @jklyn you could reword this question (and ask in meta for reopening) if you bring supporting sources for the statement "I'd heard that successful person do not sleep long". If you do, it is likely that the question be reopened. If you can't, then the question is not recoverable here.